# React query stuck in infinite loop when adding dynamic time value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I'm trying to add a Date object as a react-query variable, however whenever I use a dynamic date, instead of a static value it calls the query infinitely, instead of just once. I'm not sure of best way to break this loop or to refactor the code so that it will run only once. Can anyone see what I am doing doing wrong?

To be clear, the infinite loop happens when I replace "2022-04-20T23:40:09.038Z" with the 'today' const.

```
const MoviesPage = () => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState<TabType | undefined>(tabs?.[0]);
  const [noOfColumns, setNoOfColumns] = useState(0);
  const [{ page, titles }, setState] = useState<State>(DEFAULT_STATE);

  const handleTabClick = (tab: TabType) => {
    setState({ page: 0, titles: [] });
    setActiveTab(tab);
  };

  const today = dayjs().toISOString();

  const { data, isFetching } = useMoviesQuery(gqlClient, {
    page: page,
    limit: 16,
    afterDate: activeTab?.name === "coming-soon" && "2022-04-20T23:40:09.038Z",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFetching) {
      return;
    }
    if (data) {
      setState((v) => {
        return {
          ...v,
          titles: [...v.titles, ...data.movies],
          page: page,
        };
      });
    }
  }, [data, isFetching, setState, page]);
```

Comment: What would happen if you remove setState in your dependency array ?

Comment: Hmm yeah same issue unfortunately

Comment: well can't really help if we don't know what ```useMoviesQuery``` is, also i have a feeling  ```data``` is causing the issue. Thats, my guess.. can you try doing ```data?.movies``` ?

Comment: i would have to question the whole useEffect that writes data from the query to local state. This is usually an anti-pattern and unnecessary. If you want to keep track of multiple pages, you likely want `useInfiniteQuery` that has built in support for that.

Comment: Setters coming from "useState" shouldn't be added to the dependency array.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what `useMoviesQuery` is doing, but i would change it to the following. Passing in objects like `data` for example without accessing a property are prone to cause infinite loops(this is entirely based on my experience).

My assumption is that `useMoviesQuery` is constantly being ran based on a onChange event maybe ? therefore data is constantly being updated triggering the `useEffect`. Passing in just `isFetching` should be suffice enough to get the latest updates from `data`. That is, if `isFetching` is being updated as well. It's possibly being set from true to false within milliseconds based on the `onChangeEvent` or however this query is being trigged.

```
const MoviesPage = () => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState<TabType | undefined>(tabs?.[0]);
  const [noOfColumns, setNoOfColumns] = useState(0);
  const [{ page, titles }, setState] = useState<State>(DEFAULT_STATE);

  const handleTabClick = (tab: TabType) => {
    setState({ page: 0, titles: [] });
    setActiveTab(tab);
  };

  const today = dayjs().toISOString();

  const { data, isFetching } = useMoviesQuery(gqlClient, {
    page: page,
    limit: 16,
    afterDate: activeTab?.name === "coming-soon" && "2022-04-20T23:40:09.038Z",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFetching) {
      return;
    }
    if (!isFetching && data) {
      setState((v) => {
        return {
          ...v,
          titles: [...v.titles, ...data.movies],
          page: page,
        };
      });
    }
  }, [isFetching])
```